# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa46847dc in tid 11765 (lfontpro.source)

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in eclipse.
Why this above error is occur? I could not understand how to solve this above error.Running application stop and close automatically.
The purpose of application is make .ttf file for generate any style of font. Also i am using libttfjni.so file in my code.Also i am using multiple images.
Please any one have idea about this error.
Thank you.